# Javascript Application is crashing every 4-5 hrs in chrome and firefox

Tags: angularjs

[image: snapshot 1]

[image: snapshot 2]

[image]

My application is crashing every 4-5 hrs and I am not sure it is happening because of memory leak or any code performance issue. 
I have 3-4 functions which have timeouts to call self every 5 sec and they does some data massaging before painting the DOM.

As you can see my snapshots keep on increasing every time I take new snapshot.
Unable to find what exactly is happening. But if we look at the snapshots we can say that the strings has been increasing significantly from snapshot 1 to snapshot 9.

Any help is appreciated.

Sample code:

```
function fetchSummary() {

        if(!$rootScope.pageVisible) {
            $scope.fetchSummaryTimeout = $timeout(fetchSummary, 1000);
            $scope.lastRefreshedDateTime = new Date();
            return;
        }

            $http
                .get(apiUri + '/statusboard/api/summaryDb')
                .success(function (response) {

                    if (response && response.length) {
                            $scope.databases = response[0];
                            $scope.fetchSummaryTimeout = $timeout(fetchSummary, 5000);
                            var i, j, l;

                            //alert counts
                            angular.forEach($scope.databases.summary, function (summary) {
                                if (summary.eventType === "database_connection_alert") {
                                    $scope.connectionCount += summary.count;
                                }
                                if (summary.eventType === "database_session_alert" || summary.eventType === "database_load_alert") {
                                    $scope.warnCount += summary.count;
                                }
                            });

                            for (l = 0; l < $scope.databases.components.length; l++) {
                                var component = $scope.databases.components[l];
                                //some data stuff

                                for (j = 0; j < component.summary.length; j++) {
                                    var summary = component.summary[j];

                                    }}

                            $scope.coloCounts.any = $scope.coloCounts.All + $scope.coloCounts.lvs + $scope.coloCounts.slc + $scope.coloCounts.phx;

                            for (i = 0; i < $scope.databases.vcsStatus.length; i++) {
                                //Some stuff
                            }

                        } 
                    } else {
                        $scope.fetchSummaryTimeout = $timeout(fetchSummary, 5000);
                    }

                    angular.element("#last-updated, #last-updated-overlay").remove();

                })
                .error(function () {
                    $scope.fetchSummaryTimeout = $timeout(fetchSummary, 5000);
                });
        } 
    }
```

`"$scope.databases"` is the variable every time i set the response to.

Comment: Can you provide any code? These are usually caused by things like `setInterval` not being cleared after they are finished being used, and they keep running forever, using up more and more processing power overtime, causing your application to crash.

Comment: *strings* seem to be the culprit

Comment: I have added the sample code @MatthewW.

Comment: Try in Chrome canary (v58 at the moment) or in [much] older versions from [snapshots repo](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html).

Comment: @JaromandaX How do I resolve this string problem?